# How to deal with collinearity in a correct way in regression?

Tags: r, regression, multicollinearity

Suppose I have a task. I recruited 100 people to do the task, each performed the task 5 times and I scored them. In total, I have 500 scores.

I have an independent variable (well, let's say how much money I paid for each time one person do the task - it doesn't matter) so I want to perform a linear regression to see if the score achieved have some relations with the salary.

So, my dataframe has 500 data points. I am afraid that, due to the fact 500 data points are created by only 100 persons, it might lead to some problems relate to colinearity, and performing a linear regression on 500 scores might be not a good idea.

My question is:

1) Do I have to worry about the issue?
2) If so, what should I do to check the dependent of the score on the salary?

Thank you very much?

(If you can give example in R, it's perfect. Otherwise there is no problem)

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't expect collinearity to be a problem. (To be honest, it sounds a little like you are misunderstanding what collinearity is.)

I'd rather worry about modeling the dependence between the different trials completed by each separate individual. You have a [repeated-measures](/questions/tagged/repeated-measures) design, which is typically modeled using [mixed-model](/questions/tagged/mixed-model)s or [random-effect-model](/questions/tagged/random-effect-model)s (nomenclature differs somewhat for the same models between disciplines). There are many good textbooks and online resources out there on  repeated measures.

In R, people typically use the `lme4` or the `nlme` packages. Look at those, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. In fact, I did not check the colinearity, I just wonder if the fact that the task is repeated by one person can lead to some problems.

Comment: For repeated measure design, I wonder too. A person here repeats the task but in the same condition, so I suppose there is no between variable?

Comment: Yes, judging from your explanation, there is simply a repeated factor, i.e., the participant. So you should model the fact that observations from one participant will be much more highly correlated than observations from multiple participants. [See here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/49767/1352)